# bluetooth music choppy and cuts

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04

Running Ubuntu 22.04.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Using device Sony WF-1000XM4, device is paired and connected without any problem, but when music starts it gets micro cuts, it is choppy and even sometimes sound quality falls. The BT device works without problems with other mobile phones and laptops, so I guess the problem resides somehow in ubuntu.

Using profile `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ)` from all profiles available:

- Headset Head Unit (HSP/HPF, codec mSBC)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ)
- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC)

System does not let me select profile `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)`, it jumps automatically to `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ)`

Answer (score 2):

Posting this because I don't have enough reputation to comment (delete it if you have to, or better yet pop it in the comments), and it might add some info:

I have the exact same headphone set, and the exact same problem (except I don't have the codec SBC-XQ option for some reason), also on (K)ubuntu 22.04. A Bose bluetooth speaker works fine. This is on a 2022 Dell XPS 9520. Another machine (cca) 2019 Dell Precision 5540 with (K)ubuntu 20.04 there are no problems.

The problem occurs only sometimes, and as far as the people on Zoom calls tell me the mic works just fine, so it's just the sound that's the issue apparently.

Edit: Oops, I guess my headset is WH-1000XM4, way to name stuff, Sony

Comment: Try not doing this again. Try to improve questions and answers by editing them, and creating a useful answer. That way, you can get enough reputation.

Comment: I am not editing someone else's question to include issues I have.

Comment: No, By fixing grammatical issues, typos , improving  formatting and etc.